# Draw scrollbar over RecyclerView.ItemDecoration sticky header

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollbar, item-decoration

I am extending `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` to define a class that enables a `RecyclerView` to make header view's sticky when they are at the top of the `RecyclerView`. For this, I need to override `onDrawOver()` to draw the sticky header , since I need to draw the sticky header on top of all the other `RecyclerView` view's. This has the unfortunate side effect of also drawing the sticky header on top of the `RecyclerView`'s scrollbar. I am wondering if there is some way I can easily get the `RecyclerView` to draw it's scrollbar over this sticky header?

I've tried doing the following already:

- Mess around with `android:scrollbarStyle` XML tag on `RecyclerView`. Setting this to `outsideOverlay` does not draw the scrollbar over the sticky header.
- Move sticky header drawing logic to `onDraw()` instead of `onDrawOver()`. Doing this draws the sticky header underneath the scrollbar, but also draws it underneath the `RecyclerView`'s other views.

Any feedback is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand the problem, since you are drawing the header, can't you just make it narrower by the width of the scrollbar?

Comment: @Cheticamp Unfortunately, this is not an option. The header has a background color different from the root layout background. And the header takes the full width of the screen.

Comment: That's unfortunate. The scrollbars are drawn along with all the other _RecyclerView_ stuff and there is no hook to draw in between the item views and the scrollbar. Consider moving the scrollbar outside of the _RecyclerView_ or starting the scrollbar below the header (the top below the header.)